# How to compare values from different tables with a single query on Linq-to-SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, select

The code, with two Linq-to-SQL queries, that I am trying to optimize is below:

```
        var maxAInstant =
            (
                from a in db.As
                select a.Instant
            )
            .Max();
        var maxBInstant =
            (
                from b in db.Bs
                select b.instant
            )
            .Max();
        var interval = maxAInstant - maxBInstant;
        bool result = interval > new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
```

Can I obtain the result with a single Linq-to-SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool result = (db.As.Max(a => a.Instant) - db.Bs.Max(b => b.instant)) > new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
```

Comment: I'm no expert, but doesn't it generates two sql queries?

Comment: no way to stop it from generating two queries.  because they are tables that cannot be joined together.  from what I see.  the trick to optimizing LINQ is making sure you can do it in SQL first.

Comment: then I'll have to write a SP to get this done in a single query... thanks